# Converting a 2 digit year to a 4 digit one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

We have an entry form that gives the user a calendar drop down, but also are allowed to type in a data manually. We discovered that if a person enters a 2-digit year, the year is changed to 1912 not 2012 (dates cannot be in the past). Is there a way I can:

1. Check if they entered a 2-digit year and convert that to a 4-digit year, or
2. Give them an error if they enter a 2-digit year.

This is on an HTML form and I also am using jQuery for a bunch of other stuff.

I should clarify that they enter the date as a whole date 01/01/2012 or 1/1/2012 is valid. 1/1/12 and 01/01/12 is not.

Comment: Can you post the code that converts the 2-digit year? You can easily test for 2-digit years: $("#element_id").length!==4 { do something }. date.js is an outstanding library for things like date validation and is locale aware.

Comment: I haven't figured out anything yet since there are so many variables on how the date could be entered.

Comment: did you try to introduce drop-down or pick-date controller instead?

Comment: See first sentence: "We have an entry form that gives the user a calendar drop down, but also are allowed to type in a data manually."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest is a regexp as it will also invalidate non-numeric values;

```
​var s = $("#something").val();

if (!/^\d{4}​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​$/.test(s)) {
   alert ("Thats not a 4 digit number")​​​​​​​​​​​
   return;
```

Comment: Sorry, I added clarification on how the date is entered.

Comment: Still, a regular expression could tell if it was /\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}/ or no.  You've effectively specified the regular expression to test against when you said "... 01/01/2012 or 1/1/2012 is valid. 1/1/12 and 01/01/12 is not."  Then again, I'm rather fond of regular expressions.

I'm also assuming that your control _will_ output valid dates and so passing its output through the test may be a little redundant, but not too bad.

Comment: Thanks. I am not comfortable with Regex so that is why my mind doesn't go there. I think that will work though.

Comment: Between alex's answer and @jrnewman42's comment,  I got what I needed.

Answer (score -1):

You might want to show us some of your code.  As it is, something basic like this satisfies your 2nd requirement:

```
if ($('#yearInput').val().length() < 4) {
  alert('You must enter 4 digits');
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I added clarification on how the date is entered.